# PHP: CakePHP call to undefined function when importing it from a different Namespace

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php

I'm quite new to PHP and Namespacing. I'm trying to use cakePHP to develop a website and i'm stuck with a problem regarding the use of a function imported from a different namespace.

the problem is the following:

I've defined a Class inside a proper namespace called `App\Planner`.
The class file is also called `Planner.php` and it's located under `src/Planner/Planner.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Planner;


class Planner
{
   public static function knapSolveFast2(){

     //bunch of code
     // recursive call I missed.
     Planner::knapSolveFast2()

   }


}
```

Then I've got my controller called `ChallengesController`defined as a class inside a file also called `ChallengesController.php` under `src/Controller/ChallengesController.php` which has it's own namespace `App\Controller`. Here I've done the following:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller;
\\ some more imports
use App\Planner\Planner;

class ChallengesController extends AppController
{

  public function doThings(){
       $res = Planner::knapSolveFast2();
  }

}
```

Now when i call the endpoint /challenges/doThings it reaches the line when i call the function but then gives the following error (i'm using Xdebug to debug):

```
message = "Call to undefined function App\Planner\knapSolveFast2()"
file = "/var/www/myapp/src/Planner/Planner.php"
```

my `composer.json` autoload is set as follow:

```
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
```

can anybody explain to me what i'm missing?

**EDIT**: it seems like I missed a recursive call when I refactored the code base.

thanks

Comment: From that error message, it doesn't look like a namespacing problem, but rather that you're missing the App\Planner\knapSolveFast2() function.  Can you confirm that you have this defined?  Can you post the code where this is being called?

Comment: You seem to only have posted some example code, but are showing a real error referring to a method that doesn't exist in your simplified example. Please post all relevant code (you can remove _unrelated_ methods to keep the example small). We need to see how you actually defined the method and how you're trying to use it.

Comment: As said, you've stripped way too code and your snippet does not exhibit any issue: https://3v4l.org/arREs#v8.2.9 - Not found classes trigger "Class ... not found". Additionally, if the error comes from `/var/www/myapp/src/Planner/Planner.php` then it's clear that the file was loaded.

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to Composer itself? Please add more details to your question such that others can understand the problem better